# Need simple Postgres query for nested select query

Tags: sql, postgresql

**connection_table**

```
    app   | src_port  | dst_port |  src_ip  | dst_ip  | time  | L1  | L2  
----------+-----------+----------+----------+---------+-------+-----+----
    HTTP  | 100       | 200      |  x       | y       |  t1   | 1   | 0    
    HTTPS | 101       | 300      |  x       | y       |  t1   | 1   | 0  
    HTTP  | 102       | 200      |  a       | b       |  t2   | 0   | 1  
    HTTP  | 100       | 200      |  x       | y       |  t2   | 1   | 0
    HTTP  | 100       | 200      |  x       | y       |  t3   | 1   | 0
    HTTP  | 111       | 200      |  x       | y       |  t4   | 1   | 0
```

**Result**

```
    app   | sum(L1)  | sum(L2)  
----------+----------+--------
    HTTP  | 2        | 1  
    HTTPS | 0        | 1
```

**Query**

```
select app_table.app, 
       SUM(app_table.L1), 
       SUM(app_table.L2) 
from (
   select app, L1, L2 
   from connection_table 
   group by app, src_port, dst_port, src_ip, dst_ip
) as app_table 
group by app_table.app;
```

The above query is used to get the Result. I need a query without nested select?
Here, src_port, dst_port, src_ip and dst_ip uniquely identifies one app. Need to count total L1 and L2 for the each app.

Comment: Are you really using all those dbms's here? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: What's wrong with using the derived table?

Comment: Simple query only fits in my application. If this is the only way to get the result, it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Group By**:

Note: Your output seems wrong.

```
SELECT
    app,
    SUM(L1) AS L1,
    SUM(L2) AS L2
FROM connection_table T
GROUP BY T.app
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This will purely groups by app only. Not the real solution.

Comment: it look like your final output, is your output other then my answer?

Comment: Your output is correct, but does not work for the given requirement. Can you check with multiple entries with different "src_port" and having same application?

Comment: It's better if you provide me initial table with different src_port and then final output table

Comment: In question database table is updated. The result is same for this table also. Your query is returning HTTP|4|1                                                                                                                                                                   
HTTPS|1|0 
This is wrong result.

Comment: As per your requirement answer is perfect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124023/discussion-between-kranthi-and-sandip-patel).